# Append new table statistics to existing table next row with existing identifier

Tags: sql, sas, append

I have multiple tables all carrying information on the statistics for different zipcodes in a state. In order to do this ran a loop that went through them all so I had (zipcode1 zipcode2 zipcode2) This worked well, but now I am trying to create a master table of all the stats for each table in one appended table. How do I say

```
proc sql; 
create table wanted_all_zips 
as 
select stats 
from (
```

tables that are being overwritten each time or I can
 append the zipcode to each table so they don't get 
overwritten but I do not know how to append each 
so the next zip code is as the second/next row */

```
  ; 
    quit;
```

I have a lot of tables I don't want to be writing out  this out for each zipcode, the code could get really messy. Is there a way to say from zipcode: <--- so like * that start with zipcode union all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a loop going, you can simply do this *within it*

```
proc sql;
create table have as
select ...
;
quit;

proc append base=wanted data=have force;
run;
```

Each time this runs, it will append the contents of `have` to a master table called `wanted`

Comment: with this option sas says the variables in the have set are no tin the wanted set so it can't do it.

Comment: @JessicaWarren that should not be the case. If the `base=` table does not exist when you run `proc append` the procedure creates it. And each time you run your `proc sql`, it creates a similar output with the same table structure. So there is no reason why the `have` dataset would contain variables that are not in the `wanted` dataset. Are you sure you don't already have a dataset called `wanted` in your work library from some other code you ran?

Comment: you were correct thank you. Do you know how I would add a column where each row in that column would be named with the data table the stats came from?

Comment: PROC APPEND cannot add new columns, but you can do that with the data step method I showed below.

Comment: The easiest way would be to have the current source table's name stored in a macro variable in your loop (e.g. `&tablename`) and just add it to your select statement like this `"&tablename" as source_column`

Answer (score 2):

Use a DATA STEP with the colon modifier to get them all appended. 
INDSNAME option will identify the source data. I'm going to also guess that whatever you're doing within the loop could probably be done in another method that doesn't require splitting the dataset. The standard recommendation is to not split data in SAS unless it's an issue of space.

```
data want;
   length source source_file $256.;
   set zipcode: indsname=source ;
   source_file = source;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `union all`.  Something like this:

```
proc sql; 
    create table wanted_all_zips as 
        select stats 
        from ((select z.* from zipcode1) union all
              (select z.* from zipcode2) union all
              (select z.* from zipcode3) 
             ) z;
```

Comment: I have a lot of tables I don't want to be writing this out for each zipcode, the code could get really messy. Is there a way to say from zipcode: <--- so like * that start with zipcode union all